# Trying to display two lines inside one row in html

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am working with a project in ASP MVC and Bootstrap where I have the need to show the regulation of a transformer, this is represented in the following way:

[image]

I was trying to do it in the following way but I did not achieve the result that I intend:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">132 &#177;</td>
    <td>12x1,5 %</td>
  </tr>
  <tr style="margin-top: 0px;">
    <td>8x1.5%</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I think you may be better off using an image to represent your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is something you can start with:

```css
.txt{ height: 40px; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; }
.supsub { display: inline-block; }
.supsub sub { top: .3em !important; }
.op {  font-size: 36px }
.supsub sup, .supsub sub {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    font-size: .8em !important;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

```html
<span class="main">
    <span class="op">(</span>
    <span class="txt">
        132
    </span>
    <span class="supsub">
        <sup>&#43; 12x1,5 %</sup>
        <sub>&#8722; 8x1.5%</sub>
    </span>
    <span class="op">)/</span>
    <span class="txt">
        13,86 KV
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

You're on the right track of using `rowspan` with table. I completed it with the example below, and it's better to use `monospace` fonts.

```css
table {
  font-family: monospace;
}

td[rowspan] {
  font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2">(132</td>
    <td>+ 12x1,5 %</td>
    <td rowspan="2">)/13,86kV</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>- 8x1.5 %</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Good solution. (y)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something similar to what I've posted. If you only need to do something like this once or twice this will get you by. If you need to use math/science notations frequently it probably isn't practical.

```css
* {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align:center;
}

.container {
  width:250px;
  height:75px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  align-items:center;
}

.left {
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  height:100%;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.top-bottom {
  display:flex;
  flex:1;
  height:100%;
  flex-direction:column;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}

.top {
    display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
}

.bottom {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  width:100%;
  height:50%;
  border-top:1px solid green;
}

.right {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  flex:1;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="left">132 &#177;
  </div>
  <div class="top-bottom">
      <div class="top">12 &times; 1.5%
      </div>
      <div class="bottom">8 &times; 1.5%
      </div>
  </div>
    <div class="right">/ 13.86kV
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much i can use it!